# sum of strongly convex function and convex function with different domains

Tags: calculus, optimization

Suppose $f(\theta)=g(\theta)+h(b)$ where $\theta=(a, b)^\intercal$, $g(\cdot)$ is strongly convex and $h(\cdot)$ is convex. Note, $h(\cdot)$ may be non-differentiable. Is $f(\theta)$ strongly convex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $g$ to be strongly convex, we have $\tilde{g}(x) := g(x) - \tfrac m2 x^T I x = g(x) - \tfrac m2 \|x\|_2^2$ such that $\tilde{g}$ is convex for some $m>0$, i.e., $\nabla^2 \tilde{g} \succeq 0$. But since $h$ is convex, we have $\nabla^2 h \succeq 0$ too. So, since the sum of convex functions is convex (i.e., looking at the second derivatives), we have that $g$ is strongly convex because $\nabla^2 (\tilde{g} + h) = \nabla^2 (g+h) - \nabla^2 \left(\tfrac m 2 x^T I x\right) \succeq 0 \implies \nabla^2 (g + h) \succeq \frac{m}{2}I$.

Comment: Note, the domains are different for $g$ and $h$. What if $h$ is not differentiable?

Comment: Regarding domains, we could restrict to single dimensions for each dimension of the domains of $g$ and $h$ and use the second-derivative argument, so my answer is kind of hiding that...sorry. For the differentiability issue, I'd use the below or [this](http://xingyuzhou.org/blog/notes/strong-convexity) argument, but you may be interested in the Hessian "equivalent" of sub-gradients ([see (2.4)](https://sites.math.washington.edu/~rtr/papers/rtr158-GeneralizedHessian.pdf))

Comment: Follow your argument. If $g(x) - \tfrac m2 \|x\|_2^2$ is convex, then $g(x)+h(x) - \tfrac m2 \|x\|_2^2$ is convex since $h(x)$ is convex. Thus $g(x)+h(x)$ is strongly convex.

Comment: Ya, and we can see convexity in some informal sense by my $\nabla^2$ notation. It obscures the details of what happens when the domains are different (and not to mention the non-differentiable case), but it just takes some extra detail to look at these cases one-dimension by one-dimension at a time for the domain issue. For the differentiability issue, you could do something like that paper. But it'd be easier to do something like @angryavian's answer. So I guess my answer was a "moral" answer rather than a "detailed" answer

Answer (score 2):

I will use the notation $\theta=(\theta_1, \theta_2)$ and $\Delta=(\Delta_1, \Delta_2)$.

Strong convexity of $g$ implies $$g(\theta + \Delta) - g(\theta) - \langle \nabla g(\theta), \Delta \rangle \ge \frac{1}{2} \|\Delta\|^2.$$
Convexity of $h$ implies
$$h(\theta_2 + \Delta_2) - h(\theta_2) - h'(\theta_2) \Delta_2 \ge 0.$$

Noting that $\nabla f(\theta) = \nabla g(\theta) + (0, h'(\theta_2))$,
we have
$$f(\theta + \Delta) - f(\theta) - \langle \nabla f(\theta), \Delta \rangle \ge \frac{1}{2} \|\Delta\|^2.$$